# How can i change attribute when searching through list of objects in Python

Tags: python, arrays, object

I have a program that reads in a file with data, and then convert the data into a list of objects. 
The user can choose to search in the list based on name, age, species or gender. 
The search functions work exactly the same for all four search methods, just that the attribute is changes.

I would like to use the same method for all four attributes and just change the attribute based on users choice.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
from Animal import Animal
from searchName import searchName
from searchAge import searchAge
from searchSpecies import searchSpecies
from searchGender import searchGender


def search():
    print ("Search for: \n 1. Name \n 2. Age \n 3. Species \n 4. Gender \n")
    searchFor = int(input("Answer with number: "))

    if searchFor == 1:
        searchF = input("Name? ")
        searchName(fullset, searchF)
    elif searchFor == 2:
        searchF = int(input("Age? "))
        searchAge(fullset, searchF)
    elif searchFor == 3:
        searchF = input("Spe? ")
        searchSpecies(fullset, searchF)
    elif searchFor == 4:
        searchF = input("Gender? ")
        searchGender(fullset, searchF)
    else:
        print ("Invalid input")
```

If the user chooses 1, the searchName method is called:

```
def searchName(fullset, searchF):
    returnVal = print("No match")
    i = 0
    for djur in fullset:
        if fullset[i].name == searchF:
            returnVal = print ("Match: ", fullset[i])
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    return(returnVal)
```

How can I write the search method so that `fullset[i].name` easily can be changed to `.age`, `.species`, `.gender`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `getattr` method, which retrieves an attribute by string name.

`getattr(obj, 'attribute_name', default_value)`

So your search method would be like:

```
def searchAttribute(fullset, searchF, attribute_name):
    returnVal = print("No match")
    i = 0
    for djur in fullset:
        if getattr(obj, 'attribute_name') == searchF:
            returnVal = print ("Match: ", fullset[i])
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    return(returnVal)
```